# jQuery Thickbox with iframe - can the parameter TB_iframe=true be set initially?

Tags: jquery, iframe, thickbox

I am using the jQuery thickbox plugin to show one of my page wrapped up in a thickbox. It works fine.

This is how I call the page that is to be displayed in the thickbox.

```
 <a href="thickbox_page.html?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true" class="thickbox" id="thickbox_link">Thickbox example</a>
```

I have set the height and width parameters in the thickbox.js file itself. Similarly, can I set the other parameters also in the js file. For example, can I set TB_iframe=true in the js file, so that I need not pass the parameter in the url?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You already did that with widht and height. The TB_iframe is a parameter as well as width or height is, so why you couldn't?

Comment: There were explicit variables for width and height, TB_WIDTH and TB_HEIGHT, so I changed it. But for iframe, I am not sure where to set this variable. I am checking now by trial and error method. So thought if I post in here, if someone had done such a thing already, they could help me with that